# Calculating the price of movie tickets based on multiple inputs

Tags: c++, beginner, calculator, reference

I have modularized my code and currently my "main" function is `movieSalesReport()`. I am coming from Python where you can have the functions return multiple values. In C++ it is not so simple and I learned through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571831/can-a-function-return-more-than-one-value) that I had to use something called **referencing** in C++ in order to *mimic* returning multiple values.

My problem is that it makes my functions look stupid because it seems that they need to take in as input like a million inputs when in reality those it should really just be like `foo()` (taking in 0 inputs) but returning multiple values. There has got to be a better way! I would also appreciate just an overall code review as I am brand new to C++.

```
//
// Created by Rafeh Qazi on 12/26/15.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void getInput(string& movieName, double& adultTicketPrice,
              double& childTicketPrice, int& noOfAdultTicketSold,
              int& noOfChildTicketSold, double& percentageDonation) {

    cout << "Name of the movie: ";
    getline(cin, movieName);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Adult ticket price: ";
    cin >> adultTicketPrice;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Child ticket price: ";
    cin >> childTicketPrice;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Number of adult tickets sold: ";
    cin >> noOfAdultTicketSold;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Number of child tickets sold: ";
    cin >> noOfChildTicketSold;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Gross percentage that you would like to donate: ";
    cin >> percentageDonation;
    cout << endl;

}

void calculations(double& percentageDonation, double& grossAmount, double& amountDonated,
                  double& netSale, double adultTicketPrice, double childTicketPrice,
                  int noOfAdultTicketSold, int noOfChildTicketSold) {
    percentageDonation /= 100;
    grossAmount = adultTicketPrice * noOfAdultTicketSold + childTicketPrice * noOfChildTicketSold;
    amountDonated = grossAmount * percentageDonation;
    netSale = grossAmount - amountDonated;
}

void printReport(double percentageDonation, double grossAmount, double amountDonated, double netSale,
                 int noOfAdultTicketSold, int noOfChildTicketSold) {
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
        cout << "_*";
    }

    cout << endl;

    // movie name
        string movie = "Journey to Mars";
        cout << setfill('.') << left << setw(35) << "Movie Name: " << right << " " << movie << endl;

    // number of tickets
        cout << left << setw(35) << "Number of Tickets Sold: " << setfill(' ') << right << setw(10)
            << noOfAdultTicketSold + noOfChildTicketSold << endl;

    // gross amount
        cout << setfill('.') << left << setw(35) << "Gross Amount: " << " $" <<
        right << setfill(' ') << setw(8) << grossAmount << endl;

    // percentage of gross amount donated
        cout << setfill('.') << left << setw(35) << "Percentage of Gross Amount Donated: " <<
        right << setfill(' ') << setw(9) << percentageDonation * 100 << '%' << endl;

    // amount donated
        cout << setfill('.') << left << setw(35) << "Amount Donated: " << " $" <<
        right << setfill(' ') << setw(8) << amountDonated << endl;

    // net sale
        cout << setfill('.') << left << setw(35) << "Net Sale: " << " $" <<
        right << setfill(' ') << setw(8) << netSale << endl;
}

int movieSalesReport() {
    string movieName;
    double adultTicketPrice;
    double childTicketPrice;
    int noOfAdultTicketSold;
    int noOfChildTicketSold;
    double percentageDonation;
    double grossAmount;
    double amountDonated;
    double netSale;

    getInput(movieName, adultTicketPrice, childTicketPrice,
             noOfAdultTicketSold, noOfChildTicketSold, percentageDonation);

    calculations(percentageDonation, grossAmount, amountDonated, netSale,
                 adultTicketPrice, childTicketPrice, noOfAdultTicketSold,
                 noOfChildTicketSold);

    printReport(percentageDonation, grossAmount, amountDonated, netSale,
                noOfAdultTicketSold, noOfChildTicketSold);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of your way of defining`getInput` I would define it like the `get_student` function here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple. And I would use `std::tie` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie in order to assign a tuple instance to you variables. This is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10259473/184968

Comment: I am new in C++ so I am not exactly sure how to go about using those links that you provided as references. It is a little too abstract for me right now. The problem with Tuple in C++ is that it can only hold 2 values unlike tuples in Python. @skwllsp

Comment: @Rafeh _"The problem with Tuple in C++ is that it can only hold 2 values ..."_ Not true, a `std::tuple` can hold an arbitrary amount of values.

Comment: You are wrong about `The problem with Tuple in C++ is that it can only hold 2 values `. See the example here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple: `std::tie(gpa1, grade1, name1) = get_student(1);`

Comment: @Mat removed it. I will take a look at the example now.

Comment: @skwllsp I need to be able to return `lvalues` but the tuple forces me to return `rvalues`. I need to be able to return variables because I do not know what the user input is going to be beforehand.

Comment: I disagree with `I need to be able to return lvalues`.  You can return tuple and in `movieSalesReport()` assign its values to your variables (which are indeed lvalues)

Comment: @skwllsp how can I have my tuple return `string movieName` and then I do `cin >> movieName;` and then `double num = 5;`... At the end I do `return make_tuple(movieName, num)` and it throws an error saying you must use rvalue.

Comment: Also all those links you shared with me @skwllsp they all have a hardcoded value in the `return make_tuple` statements. When I try to have it return a variable value, it cannot do that. I need my function `getInput()` to be able to return variable values not hardcoded ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the items already mentioned in the other review, I have a few more comments and suggestions that may help you improve your code.

### Fix the bugs

Here's what happened when I used the program:

> Name of the movie: Insufferable
>
> Adult ticket price: 8.95
>
> Child ticket price: 5.95
>
> Number of adult tickets sold: 100
>
> Number of child tickets sold: 10
>
> Gross percentage that you would like to donate: 5
>
> ```
> _*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*
> Movie Name: ....................... Journey to Mars
> Number of Tickets Sold: ...........       110
> Gross Amount: ..................... $  954.50
> Percentage of Gross Amount Donated:      5.00%
> Amount Donated: ................... $   47.72
> Net Sale: ......................... $  906.77
> ```

There are two problems with it.  First, the movie name I gave was not `Journey to Mars` so that's a basic problem that comes from not passing that value into `printReport`.  The second problem is more subtle.  Notice that the gross amount is $954.50, but the sum of the donated amount and the net sale is only $954.49.  That missing $0.01 is going to drive an accountant insane!  This is a fundamental problem with using `double` (or any floating-point representation) for money values.  An alternative is to keep a number of cents as an integer value internally.  For more depth about floating point issues, I'd recommend the excellent article ["What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic"](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf) by David Goldberg.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Use objects

As mentioned in the other review, using one or more objects would help this code a lot.  Here's a start.  First you could have a class named `Movie`:

```
class Movie
{
public:
    void getInput();
    void calculate();
    void printReport() const;

private:
    std::string movieName; 
    double adultTicketPrice;
    double childTicketPrice; 
    int noOfAdultTicketSold;
    int noOfChildTicketSold; 
    double percentageDonation;

    // calculated values
    double grossAmount;
    double amountDonated;
    double netSale;
};
```

Now all of your functions are easily changed into member functions.  For example, this:

```
void getInput(string& movieName, double& adultTicketPrice,
              double& childTicketPrice, int& noOfAdultTicketSold,
              int& noOfChildTicketSold, double& percentageDonation) {
```

becomes this:

```
void Movie::getInput() {
```

And your `movieSalesReport()` is considerably simplified:

```
void movieSalesReport() {
    Movie movie;

    movie.getInput();
    movie.calculate();
    movie.printReport();
}
```

It's not ideal, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of having a bunch of unrelated variables, organize them in a `struct` or `class`:

```
 struct MovieRecord {
     string movieName;
     double adultTicketPrice;
     double childTicketPrice;
     int noOfAdultTicketSold;
     int noOfChildTicketSold;
     double percentageDonation;
     double grossAmount;
     double amountDonated;
     double netSale;
 };
```

and pass a (single) reference to your functions using it

```
void getInput(MovieRecord& movieRecord) {
    cout << "Name of the movie: ";
    getline(cin, movieRecord.movieName);
    cout << endl;
    // ...
}

void calculations(MovieRecord& movieRecord) {
    // ...
}
```

to call use the following code

```
MovieRecord mr;
getInput(mr);
calculations(mr);
```

---

Next step would be to make your free standing functions member functions of `MovieRecord`. I'll leave that as an excerise for you.

Comment: All my variables turn into unresolved variables inside the getInput function when I tried your suggestion.

Comment: @Rafeh Of course you need to reference them via the `.` operator from the instance like `movieRecord.movieName` etc.

Comment: makes sense. How do I call this function? getInput(MovieRecord)?

Comment: @Rafeh I have updated my answer with a sample for calling.

Comment: How then do my functions `calculations`, and `printReport` use the values that are outputted then from getInput(me)?

Comment: @Rafeh Use the same principle, take a reference parameter and pass the `mr` instance around. BTW Code Review might not be the best place to learn the basics of the language. There would be much more to say how to organize your code in an object oriented way. I'd recommend reading a good book, or take on a tutorial from the internet (there are plenty of these around).

Comment: I am actually writing this program from a book called C++ Programming: From Problem Analysis to Program Design by D.S. MALIK. I just wanted to organize it a bit better. I feel like the tuple would be a good way to go but I just need to see how to use it. I went to these [references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) but they all seem to have hardcoded values for the return statements of tuples. I need to have variable values returned to me in my `getInput` function.

Comment: ```int movieSalesReport() {
    MovieRecord movie;

    getInput(movie);

    calculations(movie.percentageDonation, movie.grossAmount, movie.amountDonated, movie.netSale,
                 movie.adultTicketPrice, movie.childTicketPrice, movie.noOfAdultTicketSold,
                 movie.noOfChildTicketSold);

    printReport(movie.percentageDonation, movie.grossAmount, movie.amountDonated, movie.netSale,
                movie.noOfAdultTicketSold, movie.noOfChildTicketSold);

    return 0;
}``` @πάντα ῥεῖ Is this good?

Comment: @Rafeh It's discouraged/considered bad practice to use `std::tuple` as a replacement for `struct`s. As for your last comment, no it's not good, look at my updated example.